# Running Drush returns an error

Tags: drush, 8

I am running Drush version 6.2.0 and the latest Drupal 8 beta on Dreamhosters. When I run `drush cc all` within the sites directory, I receive the following error immediately after executing the command:

> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in 
>       /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 63
>       Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.

> Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in
>       /home/mywebsite/mywebsite.com/core/includes/bootstrap.inc, line 63

Why does it happen? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12):

Drush 6 does not support Drupal 8.  You must use drush 7.0-rc1 with Drupal 8 beta 9, or drush master head with Drupal 8 head.

**UPDATE**: Drush 7 no longer supports Drupal 8; now, use Drush 8 with Drupal 8.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Drush 8 with Drupal 8 and still getting this error... Please make sure path is correct. For me it worked after setting path variable as:-

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks! I had landed in this post with a similar problem (when using drush site-install with a local Drush 8 to install Drupal 8) and setting the path to composer/vendor/bin worked fine.

Comment: Awesome! After a Drush reinstall, this turned out to be a much simpler fix.

Comment: vote up, work for me too

Comment: Where do I add this code ?

Answer (score 0):

As for Drupal 8, `drush cc all` is no longer the way to clear cache, use `drush cr` instead:

```
`cache-clear all` is deprecated for Drupal 8 and later. Please use the `cache-rebuild` command instead.                                                                  [error]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error using Drush 5.10.0 from a previous Drupal 7 project. If you have composer installed globally you can upgrade Drush to the latest version using:

```
$ composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```