# Unable to install modules with Drush

Tags: 8, drush

I've got a fresh install of the Drupal 8 Beta 12. I'm trying to install the REST UI module:

```
$ drush dl restui-8.x-1.x-dev

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in /var/www/html/drup/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 64
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in
/var/www/html/drup/core/includes/bootstrap.inc, line 64
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Tried `$ drush dl restui-8.x-1.x-dev` on a beta12 site just now and it worked immediately. First thing to do would be to try with a fresh new D8 site (beta12 or HEAD) and see if it works there. Then, if it doesn't, try and update Drush dev (`$ sudo composer update` will pull the latest dev version) and run this command again.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this when I tried to set up linux VM. Getting the same error with latest drupal.

Comment: I'm getting this error with any drush command. Any resolution?

Answer (score 6):

Drush 6 does not support Drupal 8 and you need to upgrade to drush 7 (well I just upgraded to drush 8):

```
Drush Version   :  8.0-dev
```

See duplicate issue: [Running Drush returns an error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/155084/running-drush-within-drupal-8-instance-returning-error)

**Edit:** If you are working on Drupal 8 you need the [Drupal Console](http://drupalconsole.com/) its syntax is a bit long-winded, but it is incredibly powerful.

Comment: The link to the tip is broken.