# Drush cr command error's

Tags: 8, drush

I am using drush for drupal `caches clear`, module enable/disable and so more commands.
My drush version is 5.4, it working fine for `drupal 7` but now i  creating new product in `drupal 8`.
I am using same `drush` commands for `drupal 8`. but I am facing below problems.

> D:\Drupal\site\website\docroot>drush cr
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\PluralTranslatableMarkup' not found in D:\Drupal\site\website\docroot\core\includes\common.inc on line 132
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\PluralTranslatableMarkup' not found in D:\Drupal\site\website\docroot\core\includes\common.inc on line 132
> Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                       ?[31;40m?[1m[error]?[0m
> Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\PluralTranslatableMarkup' not found in
> D:\Drupal\site\website\docroot\core\includes\common.inc, line 132

Comment: If I wanted to use Drush on my Drupal 8 site, I would need to upgrade to Drush 7.x.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/155084/40011

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy chart in the [Drush documentation](http://www.drush.org/en/master/install/#drupal-compatibility) that will explain compatibility of Drupal versions to Drush versions.

Drupal 8 requires Drush 8.x running on PHP 5.4.5+ and that is compatible with Drupal 6 and 7 as well.

Edit: Duplicate of @greg_1_anderson's answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/155103/42650